# Python-equivalent of MATLAB logical matrix from element-wise logical comparison

Tags: python, numpy, matlab, logical-operators

I am making the transition from MATLAB to Python, and am looking for a quick way to implement MATLAB's array logical comparisons. Here is an example of what I mean:

```
% Generate row vector, a, counting from 1 to 5.
>> a = 1:5;
% Generate row vector, b.
>> b = [1, 5, 4, 4, 7, 8, 1, 3,2, 10];
% Generate a 10x5 matrix which has the logical 1 (True) where the values of the two arrays are equal, and logical 0 (False) otherwise.
>> a == b'

ans = 

  10×5 logical array

   1   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   1
   0   0   0   1   0
   0   0   0   1   0
   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0
   1   0   0   0   0
   0   0   1   0   0
   0   1   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0
```

I have tried using `np.where` and other direct forms of indexing, but I cannot seem to properly imitate the MATLAB behaviour. In particular, I would like to avoid using a `for` loop (or any list comprehension) and any use of `pandas` in order to optimise performance.

Does anyone know how this is done optimally?

Comment: `a[...,None] == b`?

Comment: `where` just says where the condition array is true. It's use doesn't add anything.  What are you using in place of `b'`?  numpy 1d arrays don't change with `transpose`.  1d remains 1d. matlab always has 2d.

Comment: Don't "make the transition". Embrace both :-)

Answer (score 0):

So, I did get a solution, I'm not sure if it really is the best one, but anyways.

```
a = np.arange(1,6)
b = np.array([1, 5, 4, 4, 7, 8, 1, 3, 2, 10]).reshape(1, 10)
% or b = np.array([[1, 5, 4, 4, 7, 8, 1, 3, 2, 10]])
print(a==b.T)

[[ True False False False False]
 [False False False False  True]
 [False False False  True False]
 [False False False  True False]
 [False False False False False]
 [False False False False False]
 [ True False False False False]
 [False False  True False False]
 [False  True False False False]
 [False False False False False]]
```

Comment: `(np.array(b)[:, None] == a) + 0`

Comment: You can reshape `b` to (10,1) directly. In any case thats the right idea, comparing a (5,) wjth a (10,1) to get a (10,5) array.